# Trouble with Python's 1-element tuples and SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, integration, vectorization

I have been trying (with some success) to write vectorized integration calls with the numpy *vectorize* function but every once and a while I get stuck with issues of how Python treats tuples.

I want to write variants of integrate.quad that can integrate vector-valued functions over a grid of points.  Similarly I want to create a version of integrate.nquad that integrates over n-dimensional domains, and can compute these integrals over a grid of points (i.e an integral with an n-dimensional domain, vector output, computed along a lattice of points in k-dimensional space).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def vecint(F, I, *args):
    componentintegrals = [integrate.nquad(f, I, args) for f in F]
    retint = [CI[0] for CI in componentintegrals]
    if (len(retint)==1):
        retint = retint[0]
    reterr = np.sqrt(sum(CI[1]**2 for CI in componentintegrals))
    return retint, reterr
```

*vecint* takes as input an list of many-variable functions and treats it as an integration problem where one integrates a vector-valued function. This code works just fine, eg:

```
print(vecint([lambda x,y: np.sin(x), lambda x,y: np.cos(y)], [[0,np.pi],[0,np.pi]] ) )
print(vecint([lambda x: np.sin(x)], [[0,np.pi]]))
print(vecint([lambda x: np.cos(x), lambda x: np.sin(x)], [[0,np.pi]] ))
## and we can pass additional arguments. 
print(vecint( [lambda x,k: np.sin(x)+k], [[0,np.pi]], 1) )
```

All the above calls work as expected.  The trouble for me starts when I try to vectorize these functions.  Vectorizing integrate.quad goes fine...

```
def quad_1vz1(f, I, *args):
return np.vectorize(lambda n: integrate.quad(f, I[0], I[1], (n,)+args)[0])
```

as expected.  The above code allows for calls such as:

```
quad_1vz1(lambda x,k: np.sin(kx), [0,np.pi])(K)
```

where K=np.mgrid[0:1:6j], etc.  These are the integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi} \sin(kx) dx$$

for various values of $k$.

The problem occurs when I try to replace integrate.quad with the *vecint* function above.  eg:

```
## let's vectorize a 1-dimensional integral of a vector-valued function with one parameter. 
def vecint_2vz1(F, I, *args):
    #print(I, args)
    return np.vectorize(lambda n: vecint( F, I, (n,)+args )[0])

def f1(t,k):
    return np.cos(t)+k
def f2(t,k):
    return np.sin(t)+k

K = np.mgrid[0:1:6j]
print( vecint_2vz1( [f1,f2], [[0,np.pi]] )(K) )
```

The above results in a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

When vecint is vectorized here, the elements of K are sent as 1-element tuples of 1-element tuples, i.e. the extra argument might be something like a ((0,),).

I suspect to avoid this I have to do some crafty unpacking/repacking of arguments.... but I'm a little confused as to what Python is thinking.

It appears as if Python sometimes auto-casts 1-tuples to the value contained inside... and sometimes it does not.  This has me confused.  I feel like I'm missing something elementary.

Python's output on execution:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-8cb6f52e7d30> in <module>()
 17 ## integral of (cos(t)+k, sin(t)+k)dt for various k's.
 18 
---> 19 print( vecint_2vz1( [f1,f2], [[0,np.pi]] )(K) )

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
1809             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
1810 
-> 1811         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
1812 
1813     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
1882             if ufunc.nout == 1:
1883                 _res = array(outputs,
-> 1884                              copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
1885             else:
1886                 _res = tuple([array(_x, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=_t)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Further if I put a litle print(args) line in vecint, it prints out items such as ((a,),) where a are the elements of the mgrid K.

Comment: Instead of the entire code dump, it may be more fruitful if you are able to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where do you get the valuerror? Which assignment.  `vectorize` is not a way speed up a loop; it's hard to pass array values Through it.

Comment: @hpaulj: thanks.  The error occurs in the call to vecint_2vz1.  I'll edit in the Python tracebak.

Comment: @hpaulj: this code is not intended for anything that involves serious computation, it is primarily for convenience for some fast-to-compute vector fields, for visualization purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to trace what is going on in your code. We're trying to keep track of what `quad` takes, what your `vecint` does, `lambdas` and `vectorize`.

Why does `quad_1vz1` run, but `quad_2vz1` doesn't?  Is `quad` unpacking the tuples?  I don't know.

I tried to simplify things with:

```
def foo2(*args):
    def foo(*args):
        print(args)
        return 1
    return np.vectorize(lambda n: foo((n,)+args))
```

which produces:

```
In [148]: foo2()(np.arange(3))
((0,),)
((0,),)
((1,),)
((2,),)
Out[148]: array([1, 1, 1])
In [153]: foo2(3)(np.arange(2))
((0, 3),)
((0, 3),)
((1, 3),)
Out[153]: array([1, 1])
```

Note that since I did not specify an output type in `vectorize` it runs one step just to figure out what the output is like.  Hence I see `((0,),)` twice.  That has given other SO problems if the initial type is different from later ones (e.g. integer v float).

The 2 tuple levels are the produce of my own `(n,)+args`, and the passage of `*args` and `vectorize`.  I'd have to experiment more to sort out the responsibility of the 2nd two.

`vectorize` is a poor tool if you just want to iterate over one variable. It doesn't add speed, and it is hard to apply correctly.  It is more useful if you have several variables that you want to broadcast together.

`vectorize` with 2 arguments:

```
def foo2(*args):
    def foo(*args):
        print(args)
        return sum(*args)
    return np.vectorize(lambda x,y: foo((x,y)+args))

In [164]: foo2(10)(np.arange(2),np.arange(3,5)[:,None])
((0, 3, 10),)
((0, 3, 10),)
((1, 3, 10),)
((0, 4, 10),)
((1, 4, 10),)
Out[164]: 
array([[13, 14],
       [14, 15]])
In [166]: 10+np.arange(2)+np.arange(3,5)[:,None]
Out[166]: 
array([[13, 14],
       [14, 15]])
```

Note that I change the inner print to `print(*args)`, I see `(0, 3, 10)`.  You need to be careful when using `*args` and `args` - one's a tuple, the other isn't (or is it the other way around?).

---

If my function returns an array,  I get your error:

```
def foo2(*args):
    def foo(*args):
        print(*args)
        return np.array(*args)
    return np.vectorize(lambda x,y: foo((x,y)+args))
   .....: 
In [197]: foo2(10)(np.arange(2),np.arange(3,5)[:,None])
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

but ok with one step

```
In [203]: foo2(3)(1,2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
Out[203]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

I can specify and `object` `otypes`:

```
def foo2(*args):
    def foo(*args):
        print(*args)
        return np.array(*args)
    return np.vectorize(lambda x,y: foo((x,y)+args),otypes=[object])
   .....: 
In [206]: foo2(3)(1,2)
(1, 2, 3)
Out[206]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
In [207]: foo2(3)([1,1],[2,3])
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 3)
Out[207]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 3, 3])], dtype=object)
In [208]: foo2(10)(np.arange(2),np.arange(3,5)[:,None])
(0, 3, 10)
(1, 3, 10)
(0, 4, 10)
(1, 4, 10)
Out[208]: 
array([[array([ 0,  3, 10]), array([ 1,  3, 10])],
       [array([ 0,  4, 10]), array([ 1,  4, 10])]], dtype=object)
```

These can be stacked into an array, though in this 2d result I have to flatten as well (provided the inner arrays are all the same size).

```
In [225]: np.vstack(np.ravel(A))
Out[225]: 
array([[ 0,  3, 10],
       [ 1,  3, 10],
       [ 0,  4, 10],
       [ 1,  4, 10]])
```

I vaguely recall SO questions about `vectorize` object otypes, but I don't recall whether there were problems with this (in some versions) or it was just a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the general comments.  It seems my trouble is a little different -- vectorize appears unable to return arrays of anything that is not a standard numpy data type.  It can return an array of np.float32's.  But not an array of np.array's.  This I did not understand.  I'll have to write my own vectorization code, it appears, as I would like to go this path.

Comment: i.e. the return value of a vectorize call is always an numpy array -- it can not be a multi-dimensional array, which is what my code was assuming. :(

Comment: I didn't look close enough at where your error was occurring - in the output phase of `vectorize_call`.  There have been SO questions about making the output type `object`.

Comment: I added an `otypes=[object]` example.

Comment: Thanks, my question is answered now.  I think I rather avoid the object return, I will just vectorize float-valued functions and then promote than (not using the vectorize command) to an effectively vectorized vector-valued function.  Yuck, I don't like the term "vectorize" in this context.